# Error on hosting webservice in GoDaddy

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am trying to host a webservice on `GoDaddy`, locally its running successfully but when hosted i am getting below error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>   Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'WebService'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebService.cs" Class="WebService" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Either one of .dll file is missing on GoDaddy and also
you need to use full qualified class name (class name with namespace) in the .asmx file.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, when you say namespace is it the web service namespace - "http://tempuri.org/"? or the

Comment: Also is there a way to check dll on GoDaddy?

Comment: By namespace i refer to the namespace which you have given in your Service.cs file 
For .dlls on go daddy, you can check bin folder in your project folder which you have uploaded to go daddy

Comment: Thanks again, i have already checked and confirmed all the above. Do you have any other suggestions.?

Comment: if possible can you share your code and server details 
i will check at my end

Comment: Here is my asmx source:                  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    
}

Comment: can you please check by creating 1 new web service project and name it as webservice1 and upload to godaddy

Comment: I have already done that, but same result

Comment: if possible can i check the same on your server that will help me

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have access to server to give it to you. Can you suggest something offline.

Comment: is your web.config file present on go daddy server
if web.config file is missing then you will get this type of errors